# The conditions on marginals that guarantees a certain class of measures

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, inequality, convex-analysis

$x$ and $y$ are  $m\times n$ matrices. $a, B,C$ are $m\times 1$ matrices.   $b, A$ are $n\times 1$ matrices.

$$\sum a_i=1, 0\leq a_i\leq 1, \forall i$$

$$\sum b_j=1, 0\leq b_j\leq 1, \forall j$$

The question is what would be the necessary and sufficient conditions on $(a, b, A, B, C)$  such that there exists $(x, y)$ satisfying

$$xb=B$$

$$a^T y=A^T$$

$$yb=C$$

$$0\leq x_{ij}\leq 1,  \forall   i,j$$

$$0\leq y_{ij}\leq 1,  \forall   i,j$$

$$0\leq x_{ij}+y_{ij}\leq 1,  \forall   i,j$$

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the conditions are closed-form? I mean, the conditions form a polytope, so linear programming can easily determine the feasibility of any system $(a,b,A,B,C)$---computationally.

Comment: I want to have the closed form, i.e. getting rids of all constraints on $x, yS$ and instead representing all constraints in terms of (a,b,A,B,C). How could I show the conditions are closed form?

Comment: I know that is what you want. What makes you think it is possible?